# Overriding a built-in class method that another class I want to inherit from relies on

Tags: python-3.x, overriding, subclassing

So I'm writing a script/application that uses pythons multiprocessing BaseManager class.  Now for the most part it works great, the only issue I have is that I am using the `serve_forever` as a blocking statement and then continue onwards however when I want to terminate or exit out of the `serve_forever()` function(ality) it automatically exits out and terminates the application, but like I mentioned I have some more things I want to take care of before I completely exit out.

I can exit out of `serve_forever()` by setting a stop event with `stop_event.set()`.  Now this is all well and dandy however according to the source (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L147) `serve_forever` explicitly states `sys.exit(0)` and is part of the `Server` class that `BaseManager` uses within it's definition.  Essentially I would like to remove that line (`sys.exit(0)`).  How would I accompolish this?

When I search I'm coming up with results such as monkey patching?  Can I just Subclass the Server class, explicitly define `serve_forever` to be the exact same code but without the `sys.exit(0)` line and call it a day?  Something tells me that is not going to work. Do I subclass Server AND BaseManager?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, there's a bug in Python and I'll fix it. Second of all, why do you use the `serve_forever` method instead of `start()`? I can give you monkey patching solutions, inheritance solutions, and all other kinds of things that are an overkill and may cause more issues than they solve.

Comment: Well, I guess it was just a really convenient solution, but from what I gather your suggesting reimplement serve_forever as my own start method is the way to go?

Comment: Definitely, without a doubt.

Comment: Added an official answer so you'll be able to accept and close question if it answered your need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I really hate to keep asking but  I tried searching around but couldn't find much, I'm not actually using the multiprocessing capabilities of this library more the communication between processes capabilities and so I was actually running serve_forever in its own thread and then calling join() as away of blocking main logic but allowing other threads to run until I decide to go on, so what would the best way to accomplish creating a new start func?  Subclass and override Server class's start method? But then how do I tell BaseManager to use the subclassed Server class

Comment: So, actually I think; my original question stands... as start would be part of the Server class and BaseManager relies on that class I still need to override the Server class's function, just a different function this time... at least if the implementation I am thinking of is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239974/discussion-between-bharel-and-user1884295).

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue46022  ;  https://bugs.python.org/issue10850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to monkey-patch or inherit internal classes will result in code that will not be compatible across Python releases, not even patches.

Atop of that, these solutions will be unnecessarily complex and complicated, and are overall frowned upon.

I highly suggest re-implementing `serve_forever()` by using the `start()` method together with an event. Waiting for the event to be called or, if impossible, a loop checking if the manager is still alive, will be much easier and a better solution in almost all aspects that I can think of.

---

After discussing in chat, we realised the easiest approach is to just suppress the `SystemExit` being thrown from `sys.exit()`. I'm opening a [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue46022) on CPython bug tracker accordingly to prevent `sys.exit()`. Do keep in mind the server will not actually shut down as it is run on a different thread.  The whole recommendation of using `.server().serve_forever()` in the stdlib looks dubious at best.

If you wish to immediately shut down the server, call `Server.listener.close()` after catcing the exception.